# javascript: convert a='x1y2' into x=1 and y=2?

Tags: javascript, string, divide

I have the string x61y78 for example. How can I divide it into strings var x=61; and var y=78; using javascript?

I tried using for loops and splits but I got weird results and though there should be an easier way.

Comment: Something like this ?
`y = a.split('y')[1];
x = a.split('y')[0].split('x')[1];`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a regex :

```
"x61y78".match(/x(\d+)y(\d+)/)
```

gives you an array where the second and third element are what you want :

```
["x61y78", "61", "78"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the approach below:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str="x61y78"; 
var n="var x= "+str.slice(1,str.search("y"));
var n=n+" ; var y= "+str.slice(str.search("y")+1);
alert(n);
}
</script>
```

Output: `var x= 61 ; var y= 78`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string will be perfect as shown in the question

```
function makeVars(str){
    var arr = str.match(/[A-Za-z]|[0-9]+/g);
    // validate the array if needed
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2){
        this[arr[i]] = arr[i+1];
    }
}

makeVars("x61y78");
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

`makeVars` will add properties in the context in which it is invoked.

```
var object = {};
makeVars.call(object, "a100b200");
console.log(object.a);
console.log(object.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this, also if seems rudimental, works good:

```
var a='x32,13y89.3';
i = a.split('y');
document.write('x:'+i[0].replace('x','')+' <br> y:'+i[1]);
```

will print:
x:32,13
y:89.3

Usefull with different notations

Answer (score 0):

there is more version without assignmnent to x and y:

```
  "x61y78".match(/([0-9]+)/g);
```

result array:

```
['61','78']
```